# Store and query NxN matrix

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for a way to store and query a N x N matrix.
The data will no change frequently.
The search must be fast.

I have to be able to query the distance (and any other data stored as flights, bus, trains, others) from any city to other.

Example: 
From NY to Boston: Distance: 215 mi, Data: No trains.

From Boston to NY: Empty.

From Washington DC to NY: Distance: 225 mi, Data: -

To represent the data I made a matrix

[image]

I am working with mongoDB as a database.

**First option:** 
I am thinking in representing any row of the matrix as a document.

```
{ 
city: "NY",
destinations: [ 
    {city:"Boston", distance: "215 mi", data: "no trains"}, 
    {city:"Washington DC", distance: "226 mi", data: ""}
    ]
}
```

Cons: Some documents have an array near 4000 destination cities.

Pros: there are only 4000 documents in the collection.

**Second Option**:

Create a document with any connection of cities:

Example:

```
{
    from: "NY",
    to: "Boston",
    distance: "215 mi",
    data: "no trains"
}
```

Pros: i think that with an index it may be faster for searches.

Cons: From a 4000 x 4000 combinations, the collection may have near 12.000.000 of documents.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a pretty broad question here and really depends mostly on what the intended "query pattern" actually is.  I would *generally* be pretty loathe to have an array with 4000 or more items though unless there was a specific advantage in doing so. I suggest actually trying both and benchmarking which one works best instead of asking someone else to "greenlight" a choice for you.

Comment: Thank you Neil Lunn for your reply, but i am not looking for someone to grenlight a choise for me. Maybe there are better options that i am not considering or may be someone has experience with this and can help me.

Comment: @sebacipo: I'm with Neil here. These need to be measured/benchmarked.

Comment: @sebacipo but my intuition tells me that the first one is a terrible terrible solution. Its only advantage is that the database contains only a few supersized documents. But it's not that much of an advantage. It's not like there's a limit on number of documents in a collection. Looks like you want to use this is a proxy metric for query performance, right? That's what you need to measure, ease/performance of queries.